# Append options with multiple select into simple select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using multiple select for fill a simple select. I'm trying to if I select a value and it doesn´t exists append to simple select, if exists do not do anything, but if I unselect option, remove it from simple select. How could I do that?

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '#foo', function() {
    var values = $(this).val();

    values.forEach(function(val) {
      $('#bar option').each(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if (values.indexOf(v) === -1) {
          $('#bar').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="foo">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<select id="bar">
  <option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want to remove the remaining values from the previous select?

Comment: Nope, for example, I select value1 and value2 and them add to simple select. If I unselect value1, it must be removed from simple select, but value2 must being there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all options except the `disabled` one from `#bar` after `#foo` changed and create new options and `appendTo()` `#bar`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#foo', function() {
    var values = $(this).val() || []; // in case you don't select anything
    $('#bar option:not(:disabled)').remove()
    values.forEach(function(val) {
      $('<option>', {
        value: val,
        text: val
      }).appendTo('#bar')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="foo">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<select id="bar">
  <option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is an interesting answer. Thanks sensei

Comment: No, the selected options are not in `#bar` but `#foo`. Moreover, it is to remove the options that don't have `disabled` attribute in `#bar`, so it can't be `:checked`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to empty the children upon every change or else the new `<option>`s will get appended and the list becomes very long. Try this:

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '#foo', function() {
    var values = $(this).val();
    $('#bar').empty().append('<option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>');
    values.forEach(function(val) {
      $('#bar option').each(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if (values.indexOf(v) === -1) {
          $('#bar').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="foo">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<select id="bar">
  <option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `click` event rather than `change`, because if you click same option twice, change event cannot be listened.
You can try the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  //get onclick value
  $(document).on('click', '#foo', function() {
    let value = $(this).val();

    //get existing values in #bar
    let exist = false;
    $("#bar option").each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == value){
        exist = true;
    //remove if exist
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
  //append if not exist
  if(!exist){
      $('#bar').append(`<option value="${value}">${value}</option>`);
}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="foo">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<select id="bar">
  <option selected disabled value="default">Add some from multiple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're going to have more problems than this I think, but if you're just looking how to remove an option, you could do something like this

```
$("#bar option([value=" + val+ "]").remove();
```